# rabbitmq_parameter module json argument

Tags: json, rabbitmq, ansible

I'm trying to use the rabbitmq_parameter ansible module to set a federation upstream set, while dynamically generating the set, with something like this:

```
- name: Set federation upstream set
  rabbitmq_parameter:
    component: federation-upstream-set
    name: my-upstreams
    vhost: my-vhost
    value: "{{ my_upstream_set }}"
```

The variable my_upstream_set is defined in a separate host variable file, like so:

```
my_upstream_set: [{"upstream": "upstream1"}, {"upstream": "upstream2"}]
```

However, no matter how I generate the value argument, which must be json, (with or without quotes, with simple or double quotes, yaml or json formatted), I can't get this to work. I get either the task failing with "stderr: Error: JSON decoding error", or the following error:

```
failed: [myhost] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
invalid output was: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1498, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 142, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 104, in set
  File "<stdin>", line 88, in _exec
  File "<stdin>", line 1351, in run_command
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 261, in expanduser
    if not path.startswith('~'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 1
```

I've tried running the task with a hardcoded value (so, directly in the task file) and it works as expected, but I have no way of integrating variables into that. Any idea what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`my_upstream_set` should be a JSON (string) in your case it is a list.

Comment: Well here the parameter is implicitly converted to a string. I tried to pass ``{{ my_upstream_set|to_json }}`` as well, and it didn't work either.

Comment: Will it work if you replace the `value : {{ my_upstream_set }}` with `value: '[{...}, {...}]' ` ?

Comment: I works with value: ``'[{"upstream": "upstream1"}, {"upstream": "upstream2"}]'``

Comment: will it work if you do the following: in the vars file: `my_upstream_set: '[{"upstream": "upstream1"}, {"upstream": "upstream2"}]'` and in the playbook `value: '{{ my_upstream_set }}'` ?

Comment: No, it still gives me the "'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'" error